# Integrate Blogengine.net 2.5RC with an MVC2 .NET4 website on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, azure, blogengine.net

I'm looking for a simple way to integrate Blogengine.NET 2.5RC with an existing MVC2 site running in Azure.  I'd like for the integration to be done thru Visual Studio solution and for all the code to reside in one solution or project so that I can publish seamlessly.

My current MVC solution is targetting .NET4 framework

All the examples on the net I'm finding are either targeting old version of BlogEngine.NET that needs .NET2 or non-Azure deployments which cater to creating virtual directories post deployment time... (something Azure doesn't do well)

Truthfully, I've been sleep deprived for the last six weeks now and just need something very simple, so I can follow step-by-step instructions :)

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Why don't you use the power of full IIS and leverage the Virtual Directory? Does it really need to be created post deployment? You can set up virtual directories in you csdef file. If you post the link to what you've seen using virtual directories i'd be willing to take a look.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did... this post dates sometime ago, thanks Cory

Answer (score 0):

You can now, since June 2012, also opt for Windows Azure Web Sites. You can publish from either Git, TFS or via FTP.

To learn more about it you can take a look at https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/.